# how to solve mongo collection 1000,000 records join elasticsearch index 200,000,000 records?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

**Question context**:

1. We store the app's package, such as `com.demo.apk`, in a mongo collection called `app`.
2. We store the app's installer in an elastic-search index called `app_installer`.
3. App related app_installer with the package.
4. Now we want to execute a SQL like:
   `select * from app_installer where package in (pkglist);`
   pkglist is searched from app about 50,000 records.

**Note**:

- **App**: lower frequency to insert by timer or manager and to update by customer or manager,about 1000,000 records.
- **app_installer**: generate full data per day,about 200,000,000 records

**And my question is how to search in 4 seconds? or how to reorganize data structure to reach?**

Comment: pkglist is searched from app about 500,000 records